# How to add data annotations to partial class in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, data-annotations

this is my CLASS:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations


Public Class Class1
Public Property id As Integer

<Required(ErrorMessage:="First Name is required.")> _
<Display(Name:="fname")> _
<MaxLength(10)> _
Public Property fname As String

<Required(ErrorMessage:="Last Name is required.")> _
<Display(Name:="lname")> _
<MaxLength(12)> _
Public Property lname As String

<Range(100000, 1200000)>
Public Property salary As Decimal
End Class
```

Is possible to use data annotations in partial Class in ASP.NET WebForms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the full MVC architecture. This is your model and you can pass it into the Partial View as a parameter.

There are many tuorials on MVC and partial views - try this one http://rachelappel.com/razor/partial-views-in-asp-net-mvc-3-w-the-razor-view-engine/ or any of the official MVC tutorials

There are also plenty of examples on Stack Overflow.

Good luck